# В "Электронном Рае" или "Раю"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания

Все знают, что правильно: "о рае", но *"в раю".*

Но если мы говорим о магазине под названием *"Электронный Рай"* (на Пражской в Москве), действует ли это правило? Если в этом случае уже правильно *"в Электронном Ра**е**"*, то чем это можно объяснить?

В пользу варианта *"в Электронном Рае"* говорит Google, который дает 4 120 результатов на эту закавыченную фразу против 2 410 на *"в Электронном Раю".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей видимости, вариант "в электронном ра**е**" возникает от необходимости обращаться с применённой в названии метафорой (комфортное место условно сопоставляется с Раем) иначе, чем с лежащей в её основе сущностью. Повторение особенностей употребления исходного слова способно разрушить *условность* метафоры и в некоторых оборотах придаёт слову излишнюю *буквальность*, а звучанию названия -  навязчивость, как и в случаях "учёные мужья" (соотв., *не* "мужи двух подруг"), "сыновья отечества", "сукины сыновья" и т. п. Поэтому здесь оправдано грамматическое *размежевание переносного смысла* "рая" с *прямым*. Точно так же было бы с каким-нибудь деревянно-строительным супермаркетом "Норвежский лес": *давай завтра встретимся в "Норвежском лес**е**"* (вместо обычного "в... лес**у**").

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Нравится мне ответ! Я тоже самое чувствовал, но важно было это правильно сформулировать и найти подтверждение ощущениям.

Comment: Ой, конечно, "то же", а не "тоже"!

Comment: Однако я сейчас в театральной передаче услышал *в "Вишнёвом саду".*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Если сомневаетесь, тогда вот [справка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_65): *формы на –у не употребляются, если существительные входят в состав названий произведений, поэтому правильно: в «Вишнёвом саде»...*.

Comment: @grizzly: интересно, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: **в "Электронном Рае" (П. п.).**

**Пояснение**

**1) Современный предложный падеж включает в себя окончания двух падежей:** основное окончание Е объектного, или изъяснительного падежа, и вариантное окончание У/Ю местного, или обстоятельственного, падежа.

**2) Окончание У/Ю** употребляется  при **обстоятельственном значении**: гулять в лесу, в саду, **а окончание  Е** – при **объектном** значении существительного: говорить о лесе, о саде. Также  окончание У/Ю употребляется в разговорном стиле стиле, а Е – в книжном стиле: на бале (нейтр.) и на балу (разг.).

3) Если географические названия встречаются в названиях литературных произведений, то в них употребляется  **окончание Е**: в «Вишневом саде» Чехова, в «Восемнадцатом годе» Толстого.

4) Аналогично можно предположить, что в  "Электронном Рае" будет использовано **окончание предложного (объектного) падежа Е**.

Comment: Спасибо, Сибилла! А можете мне ещё ответить на последние комментарии в вопросе про "новоприбывшего"? Спасибо!

Comment: Sharon, только что Сергей Безруков сказал по радио *в "Вишнёвом саду".* Я, собственно, случайно включил передачу, искал другую в интернете, но увидел, что сейчас передача с Калягиным, и захотелось услышать его голос.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, тут не о чем спорить. Только ***в "Электронном рае"***. Здесь имя собственное, а к ним критерии использования местного падежа как правило не применимы. Все остальные аргументы (хотя среди них есть и разумные) просто избыточны. Сравните, если человек имеет фамилию Нос (или прозвище, как замечательный Фрунзик Мкртчян), то вы не скажете, что "на Носу была надета шляпа/очки"? Только "на Носе".

Если бы это была обычная метафора, то оба варианта были возможны. Но вариант "в электронном рае" всё равно выглядит предпочтительно. Вот для этого случая позволю себе некоторую аргументацию привести.

Вообще только одно слово по традиции последовательно требует или хотя бы допускает "местный падеж" (местную форму предложного) во всех случаях использования предложного падежа, включая вопрос "о чем?". Это слово "полк" (*в нашем полку, о нашем полку*), да и оно сейчас теряет это свойство. Все остальные в разных контекстах, например при использовании с определениями, допускают обычную форму. Причем чем больше этого контекста, тем явственнее проступает необходимость отказа от местной формы. Крайний случай, как уже сказала, имена собственные. Эпитеты еще не перешли в категорию, где местная форма невозможна, но дело к тому идет. Плюс прилагательное, тоже не способствующее сохранению местного падежа. 
Таким образом, даже при метафорическом употреблении предпочтительнее "в электронном рае". А уж как имя собственное - однозначно.

PS Гугл не аргумент. По нему получается, что более одной трети его пользователей - безграмотны. )))

Comment: Спасибо, Ирина! *По нему получается, что более одной трети его пользователей - безграмотны. )))* Ну, это не новость. То же самое будет, если посмотреть безграмотное "стелЯтся" — тоже куча вариантов. ;)